# I get an JS error Opal.const_get_relative is not a function when compiling ruby into js

Tags: ruby, opalrb

I have a Ruby function translated into JS by Opal that has always worked fine, but suddenly it does not work anymore.
The JS console gives me this error message

```
Opal.const_get_relative is not a function
```

The original Ruby code is this

```
Document.ready? do
  Element.find('#button_id').on :click do
```

Which translates into this

```
  return $send(Opal.const_get_relative($nesting, 'Document'), 'ready?', [], (TMP_1 = function(){var self = TMP_1.$$s || this, TMP_2;

  return $send(Opal.const_get_relative($nesting, 'Element').$find("#button_id"), 'on', ["click"], (TMP_2 = function(){var self = TMP_2.$$s || this, TMP_3, postcode_value = nil, blokouderling = nil, content = nil, wijk = nil, naam = nil, email = nil, $writer = nil;
```

Any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: How are you compiling the ruby code? Maybe you're loading the Opal code from the CDN?

Comment: I'm compiling the code in a rakefile like this:      `File.open("app/blokouderling_lookup.js", "w+") do |out|
    out << Opal.compile(File.read('app/blokouderling_lookup.rb'))`

The js code runs inside a Wordpress site. In there I've uploaded the latest opal code.

Comment: My advice is to use `Opal::Builder` and produce a single file for everything in it like in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to compile an opal app to a file outside of Rails is to build the JavaScript file with `Opal::Builder`, here's a simple example with both Opal and jQuery:

```
gem 'opal', '~> 0.11.4'
gem 'opal-jquery', '~> 0.4.3'

require 'opal'
require 'opal-jquery'

app_html = <<-HTML
  <html><head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head><body></body></html>
HTML

app_code = <<-RUBY
  Document.ready? do
    alert('hello world!')
  end
RUBY

builder = Opal::Builder.new
builder.build('opal')
builder.build('opal-jquery')
builder.build_str app_code, 'app.rb'

File.write 'app.js', builder.to_s
File.write 'app.html', app_html
```

At that point you can just open `app.html` with your browser to see the "hello world" message popping up in an alert.